# I want to add a picture to an item in my menu

Tags: java, android

I want to add a picture to an item in my menu. I've found many solutions on the internet but none of them seems to work.

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0,0,0,"pic 1");
    menu.getItem(0).setIcon(R.mipmap.pic1);
```

(nothing happens)

Also I am trying to create a menu using Contextual Action Mode like this:

```
>   private ActionMode.Callback callback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_mode_context_menu_layout,menu);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.left:
                    TV2.setText("Selected: Left");
                    TV2.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                    break;
                case R.id.right:
                    TV2.setText("Selected: Right");
                    TV2.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    break;
                case R.id.middle:
                    TV2.setText("Selected: Middle");
                    TV2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
        TV2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TV2.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                ActionMode mode = ((Activity)v.getContext()).startActionMode(callback);
                return true;
            }
        });
}
```

I've also tried like this:

```
ActionMode mode = ((AppCompatActivity)v.getContext()).startSupportActionMode(callback);
```

and in both cases nothing happens

Comment: Overflow menu items do not have icons.

Comment: Welp, I got a task that specifically says to add an icon to a menu item.

Comment: If by "menu item" you mean "overflow menu item" of the action bar or `Toolbar`, I am not aware of a supported way to do that, as such icons go against the Material Design guidelines, and Google's implementation does not support it as a result. Icons are only used on actual toolbar-style buttons on the action bar/`Toolbar` itself (e.g., `showAsAction` set to `always` or `ifRoom`).

Comment: I mean your standard menu on the app bar, the one you call by clicking the three dots.

Comment: That's the overflow, and icons are not supported there.

Comment: Yeah so I've read somewhere else that it's no longer supported since Android 3.0. Can I somehow reverse back to an earlier version of Android?

Comment: You know what, forget it, the Context Action Mode bit is way more important. What about that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to add icon to navigation view ?

You can just use the icon tag

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_clubs"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_clubs"
        android:title="cool"/>
```

And add it to the drawer with this :

```
  app:menu="@menu/your_group_of_item"
```

Comment: the android:icon tag doesn't do anything to me.And I am not sure what you mean about the drawer or where to put app:menu